# how to overcome"java.sql.Clob is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces" issue

Tags: jaxb

I am making an jaxbcontext newInstance, passing DO as a class.My DO contains java.sql.clob as one of the fields.
This clob field is creating an issue while creating a new Instance. Giving error as
Exception occured While  capturing clob

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.sql.Clob is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.sql.Clob
        at public java.sql.Clob com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO.getXmlString()
        at com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO
The type of the getter is java.io.InputStream but that of the setter is long. They have to be the same.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public abstract java.io.InputStream java.sql.Clob.getAsciiStream() throws java.sql.SQLException
        at java.sql.Clob
        at public java.sql.Clob com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO.getXmlString()
        at com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public abstract java.io.OutputStream java.sql.Clob.setAsciiStream(long) throws java.sql.SQLException
        at java.sql.Clob
        at public java.sql.Clob com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO.getXmlString()
        at com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO
The type of the getter is java.io.Reader but that of the setter is long. They have to be the same.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public abstract java.io.Reader java.sql.Clob.getCharacterStream() throws java.sql.SQLException
        at java.sql.Clob
        at public java.sql.Clob com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO.getXmlString()
        at com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public abstract java.io.Writer java.sql.Clob.setCharacterStream(long) throws java.sql.SQLException
        at java.sql.Clob
        at public java.sql.Clob com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO.getXmlString()
        at com.data.subscriber.SubscriberProvTransDO

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:66)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:210)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:368)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at com.business.system.handler.EventProcessorHandler.insertFailure(EventProcessorHandler.java:286)
    at com.business.system.handler.EventProcessorHandler.processRequest(EventProcessorHandler.java:184)
    at com.business.system.EventProcessorBean.onMessage(EventProcessorBean.java:51)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMdbMethod(MessageEndpointHandler.java:1086)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:773)
    at $Proxy6.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaEndpointInvokerImpl.invokeEndpoint(JmsJcaEndpointInvokerImpl.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaDispatcher.dispatch(SibRaDispatcher.java:768)
    at com.ibm.ws.sib.ra.inbound.impl.SibRaSingleProcessListener$SibRaWork.run(SibRaSingleProcessListener.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:419)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  The XML adapter will convert the unmappable object `java.sql.Clob` to a mappable object such as `String`:

**ClobAdapter**

```
import java.sql.Clob;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ClobAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Clob> {

    @Override
    public Clob unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // Convert String to Clob
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Clob v) throws Exception {
        // Convert Clob to String
    }

}
```

**Root**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` must be set on the Clob property.  This annotation is how you link in the `XmlAdapter`:

```
import java.sql.Clob;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class Root {

    private Clob clob;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ClobAdapter.class)
    public Clob getClob() {
        return clob;
    }

    public void setClob(Clob clob) {
        this.clob = clob;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise,I tried this before but is not helping me and giving the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: @ABC - Could you try the short demo in my answer and let me know if you see an exception?

Comment: Hey, Demo does work for me. Now confused why it is not working for my project

Comment: I was wrongly placing annotations and hence the error. It is now workign properly..Thanks for all your help.